# The sequence $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}, a_2 = 1, a_{n+1} = \frac{na_n+1}{a_{n-1}+n}$ is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}$ defined by $$a_1 = \frac{1}{2}, a_2 = 1, a_{n+1} = \frac{na_n+1}{a_{n-1}+n}, \forall n\ge 2.$$
>   Prove that $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 3}$ is decreasing.

I get the first $200$ values of $\{a_n\}$ and recognize this fact, but I cannot prove it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = 1$ and $a_{3} = \frac{6}{5}$

Comment: $$a_{n+1} = a_{n}+\frac{1-a_{n}a_{n-1}}{n+a_{n-1}}$$ hence in order to prove that $a_n$ is decreasing from some point on, it is enough to prove that $a_{n}a_{n-1}>1$ from some point on.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 How do you prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 1$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, but proving that is not easy.

Comment: take $\lim a_n=l$, you get, $l=\frac{nl+1}{l+n}$

Comment: @MANMAID Yes, if you can prove that $\{a_n\}$ converges, things become easy.

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n-1} = a$. Put this in the recurrence, to get $a^2=1$.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 But how do you prove that $\{a_n\}$ has a finite limit?

Comment: my intuition says take $a_n=x_n/y_n$, and then re frame the problem, may be I am wrong.

Comment: Calculate $a_3$ and use Jack's answer.

Comment: @Horstenson Could you prove $a_na_{n-1}>1$ from some point on, please? I found it not so easy to prove.

Comment: To prove $a_na_{n-1}>1$ it suffice to prove $a_n \gt 1, n \ge 3$

Comment: @EugenCovaci I also tried it, but things just went around and around.

Comment: Testing various seed values, including complex numbers, the sequence appears to always converge to $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From comments: it would appear that part III is not relevant for the original question. Plus, if we drop part III, the remaining induction hypotheses take effect with smaller $n.$ On the other hand, finding III is what allowed me to solve the problem; together, parts III and IV give a quite precise rate of convergence. I put in some lines of symbols to divide the parts.

Take $$ a_n = 1 + \delta_n $$

I get
$$ 1 + \delta_{n+1} = \frac{n+1+ n \delta_n}{n+1+ \delta_{n-1}}  $$

The induction hypotheses become extensive, and are true for $n \geq 8:$

$$ \mbox{I:} \hspace{20mm}  \delta_n > 0, $$
$$ \mbox{II:} \hspace{20mm}  n \delta_n < 1, $$
$$ \mbox{III:} \hspace{20mm}  n \delta_n > (n-3) \delta_{n-1} > \delta_{n-1}, $$
$$ \mbox{IV:} \hspace{20mm}  n \delta_n < (n-2) \delta_{n-1}. $$

We begin with part III using only the $n \delta_n > \delta_{n-1}$,
$$ 1 = \frac{n+1}{n+1} < \frac{n \delta_n}{\delta_{n-1}}, $$
[by the ``mediant'' inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_%28mathematics%29) 
$$ 1 = \frac{n+1}{n+1} <  \frac{n+1+ n \delta_n}{n+1+ \delta_{n-1}}   <\frac{n \delta_n}{\delta_{n-1}}, $$
$$ 1 = \frac{n+1}{n+1} <  1 + \delta_{n+1} < \frac{n \delta_n}{\delta_{n-1}}, $$
and $$  0 < \delta_{n+1}.  $$ This was the  induction step part I.

Context: in the setting of [(simple) continued fractions,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) with two consecutive convergents (let's say it is for a positive irrational), when the "partial quotient" $a_n$ is equal to $1,$ the next convergent $\frac{h_n}{k_n}$ is the mediant of the previous two.
$$\frac{h_n}{k_n} = \frac{a_n h_{n-1}+ h_{n-2}}{a_n k_{n-1}+ k_{n-2}}  $$
Whatever $a_n$ might be, the new convergent is between the  two given.

$$  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc   $$

From part II we get
$$ 1 + \delta_{n+1} = \frac{n+1+ n \delta_n}{n+1+ \delta_{n-1}} < \frac{n+2}{n+1+ \delta_{n-1}} <  \frac{n+2}{n+1} = 1 +   \frac{1}{n+1}, $$
$$ \delta_{n+1} <   \frac{1}{n+1}. $$
This was induction part II.
$$  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  $$

Back to III, we have
$$ \delta_{n-1} < \left( \frac{n}{n-3} \right) \delta_n. $$ So
$$  1 + \delta_{n+1} > \frac{n+1+ n \delta_n}{n+1+  \left( \frac{n}{n-3} \right) \delta_n}. $$
$$       n+1 + (n+1) \delta_{n+1} +    \left( \frac{n}{n-3} \right)  \delta_n (1 + \delta_{n+1}) > n+1 + n \delta_n.               $$
$$        (n+1) \delta_{n+1} +    \left( \frac{n}{n-3} \right)  \delta_n (1 + \delta_{n+1}) >  n \delta_n.               $$
$$ 1 + \delta_{n+1} < \frac{n+2}{n+1}  $$
$$        (n+1) \delta_{n+1} +    \left( \frac{n}{n-3} \right)  \left( \frac{n+2}{n+1} \right)  \delta_n  >  n \delta_n.               $$
For $n \geq 7,$
$$ \frac{n^2 + 2n}{n^2 -2n-3} < 2. $$
For $n \geq 7,$
$$    (n+1) \delta_{n+1} > (n-2) \delta_n  $$
This was induction part III.
$$  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  $$

In the other direction, part IV gives
$$ \delta_{n-1} > \left( \frac{n}{n-2} \right) \delta_n. $$ 
$$  1 + \delta_{n+1} < \frac{n+1+ n \delta_n}{n+1+  \left( \frac{n}{n-2} \right) \delta_n}. $$
$$       n+1 + (n+1) \delta_{n+1} +    \left( \frac{n}{n-2} \right)  \delta_n (1 + \delta_{n+1}) < n+1 + n \delta_n.               $$
$$       (n+1) \delta_{n+1} +    \left( \frac{n}{n-2} \right)  \delta_n (1 + \delta_{n+1}) <   n \delta_n.               $$
$$       (n+1) \delta_{n+1} +    \left( \frac{n}{n-2} \right)  \delta_n <   n \delta_n.               $$
$$  \frac{n}{n-2} > 1  $$
$$       (n+1) \delta_{n+1} <   (n -1) \delta_n.               $$
This was induction part IV.
$$  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  $$

Comment: This is correct (although I must say it's a bit hard to follow), and it follows directly from $(II)$ that $\delta_n\to 0$ and hence $a_n\to 1$. From $(IV)$ it follows that $\delta_{n-1}>\frac{n}{n-2}\delta_n>\delta_n$, so the sequence is decreasing. All in all, good job! +1

Comment: The step using mediant inequality is not correct, but it doesn't matter much. Thank you.

Comment: @TienKhaPham, if we have $a,b,c,d > 0,$ and $\frac{a}{c} < \frac{b}{d},$ then $\frac{a}{c}< \frac{a+b}{c+d} < \frac{b}{d},$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_%28mathematics%29

Comment: @WillJagy My mistake. It's all correct, thank you so much.